# deserialize list of XElement without list root member

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight-5.0, xml-deserialization

In my case I've a XMLTAG `<phrase>` that can contains one or more XMLTAG `<q>` but they can appear in phraseTag value in a random order. 
Here it is an example of xmlcode:

```
<phrase level="1">
  Where 
  <q>are</q> 
  <subject>you</subject> 
  <q>going?</q>
</phrase>
```

For deserialization I'm using this class:

```
[XmlRoot("phrase")]
public class Phrase
{
  public Phrase()
  {
    this.Quoted = new List<string>();
  }

  [XmlAttribute("level")]
  public int Level { get; set; }
  [XmlElement("subject")]
  public string Subject { get; set; }
  [XmlText]
  public string Value { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("q")]
  List<string> Quoted { get; set; }
}
```

My extension method is:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this XElement xElement)
{
  try
  {
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xElement.CreateReader());
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

When I deserialize XML document all class members are successfully serialized:

```
Phrase.Level = 1
Phrase.Subyect = "you"
Phrase.Value = "Where"
```

How can I deserialize `<q>` tags?
I've tried to use `XmlArrayAttibute` and `XmlArrayItemAttibute` but I have not a member for this list (eg. QTags).

Comment: Use XmlArray and XmlArrayItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `XmlElement` attribute :)

```
[XmlRoot("phrase")]
public class Phrase
{
    [XmlElement("q")]
    public List<string> q { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("level")]
    public int Level { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I'm looking for something like this in my class: List<string> Quoted { get; set; }. How can I use XmlElementAttribute on this kind of property?

Comment: Sorry! I haven't seen the property q! Anyway this don't work for me. After deserialization my List<string> q has Always Count = 0!

Comment: Noooooooo! I forgot the "public" keyword!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot, I' an idiot programmer :D